# How can I generate a range of IP addresses in Perl?

Tags: perl, ipv4

I need to generate a list of IP-addresses (IPv4) in Perl. I have start and end addresses, for example 1.1.1.1 and 1.10.20.30. How can I print all the addresses inbetween?

Comment: Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: I need to automate some system administration tasks. Yes, with perl

Comment: Well, stranger things have been done with Perl.

Comment: I might be missing a joke, but system administration is one of Perl's most common applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::IP#looping)'s looping feature:

> The `+` operator is overloaded in order to allow looping though a whole range of IP addresses:

Answer (score 8):

Use [Net::IP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::IP). From the CPAN documentation:

```
my $ip = new Net::IP ('195.45.6.7 - 195.45.6.19') || die;
# Loop
do {
    print $ip->ip(), "\n";
} while (++$ip);
```

This approach is more flexible because Net::IP accepts CIDR notation e.g. 193.0.1/24 and also supports IPv6.

Edit: if you are working with netblocks specifically, you might investigate [Net::Netmask](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Netmask).

Comment: I would prefer these URLs: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::IP and http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Netmask

Comment: @Sinan I felt that my answer added enough additional information to be worth posting. The counter question: why -shouldn't- I provide helpful information to the OP? How does it harm anyone?

Answer (score 3):

It's all in how you code it. This is the fastest way I know.

```
my $start = 0x010101; # 1.1.1
my $end   = 0x0a141e; # 10.20.30

for my $ip ( $start..$end ) { 
    my @ip = ( $ip >> 16 & 0xff
             , $ip >>  8 & 0xff
             , $ip       & 0xff
             );
    print join( '.', 1, @ip ), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TMTOWTDI:

```
sub inc_ip { $_[0] = pack "N", 1 + unpack "N", $_[0] }
my $start = 1.1.1.1;
my $end = 1.10.20.30;
for ( $ip = $start; $ip le $end; inc_ip($ip) ) {
    printf "%vd\n", $ip;
}
```

Comment: For those too lazy to google it - "Theres More Than One Way To Do It"

Comment: Does this method prevent your numbers from exceeding 255? sorry i'm having a hard time reading it, I'm not familiar with unpack and well for some reason all search engines on my netwok seem to be down (can't get to bing, yahoo, or google, in no particular order)

Comment: @onaclov2000: perldoc -f pack, perldoc -f unpack, perldoc perlpacktut
Yes, it prevents them from exceeding 255.

Answer (score 0):

```
# We can use below code to generate IP range

use warnings;
use strict;
my $startIp = $ARGV[0];
my $endIp = $ARGV[1];
sub range {
my (@ip,@newIp,$i,$newIp,$j,$k,$l,$fh);
my ($j1,$k1,$l1);
open($fh,">","ip.txt") or die "could not open the file $!";
@ip = split(/\./,$startIp);
for($i=$ip[0];$i<=255;$i++) {
  for($j=$ip[1];$j<=255;$j++) {
    $ip[1]=0 if($j == 255);
     for($k=$ip[2];$k<=255;$k++) {
        $ip[2]=0 if($k == 255);
        for($l=$ip[3];$l<=255;$l++) {
            $ip[3]=0 if($l == 255);
            @newIp = $newIp = join('.',$i,$j,$k,$l);
            print $fh "$newIp \n";
            exit if ($newIp eq $endIp);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
range ($startIp, $endIp);
```