# IP address conditional statement in perl

Tags: perl, ip-address, conditional-statements

We have a one Perl script in our system which authenticate the IP address from our group.
The script was developed by a previous developer and I am not fluent in Perl.
We have a set of IPs which are hard coded and check before it perform an operation.
Here is the code snippet(example):

```
unless ($remoteip eq "some ip" || $remoteip eq "some IP" || $remoteip eq   "xx.xx.xx.xx" )
```

Now I want to add another 50 IP addresses which are in range (xx.xx.xx.145 to xx.xx.xx.204)
I don't want to add each of them one by one in **Unless** statement because that will be lengthy and not good to programing (I think).
Is there any way I can add a "Less than" or "greater than" statement for IP address?
Something like Unless($remoteip <="xx.xx.xx.204" AND $remoteip >= "xx.xx.xx.145").

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think this is *quite* a duplicate, but have you seen this SO question? [How can I generate a range of IP addresses in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279756/how-can-i-generate-a-range-of-ip-addresses-in-perl)

Comment: Your problem could be rephrased as "address is a valid IP address and starts with these three octets and the last octet is larger than or equal to x and less than or equal to y". Implementing that, as they say, is a simple matter of programming. (Once you will want to straddle a /24 boundary, things will get more interesting.)

Answer (score 2):

Convert the quad to an 32-bit integer and you're set.  There are some modules on CPAN that will do it for you but it boils down to something like this

```
sub ip2dec ($) {
    unpack N => pack CCCC => split /\./ => shift;
}

if (ip2dec($remoteip) <= ip2dec('xx.xx.xx.204') && ip2dec($remoteip) >= ip2dec('xx.xx.xx.145')) {
   # do something
}
```

For example `111.222.233.244` is converted to `1876879860` (`0x6fdee9f4`, `01101111110111101110100111110100`).
So you can not only compare (order) addresses, but you can also apply bit masks to it.

Comment: thanks this worked! I have to make few tweaks as per my code but got it eventually.

Comment: I'd prefer a different style when converting the IP: `unpack('N', pack('C4', split(/\./, $_[0])));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Socket module with the inet_aton method and covert a range into an array and grep through that.

```
use v5.16;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Socket qw/inet_aton/;
#using 10.210.14 as the first three octects
#convert range into binary
my @addressrange = map {unpack('N',inet_aton("10.210.14.$_"))} (145..204);
#address to test
my $address = $ARGV[0];
#grep for this binary in the range
unless(grep {unpack('N',inet_aton($address)) eq $_} @addressrange) {
  say "Address not part of the range"
}
else {
  say "Address is part of the range"
}
```

And then to run

```
perl iphelp.pl 10.210.14.15
Address not part of the range

perl iphelp.pl 10.210.14.145
Address is part of the range
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal to handle the logic yourself, but as has been pointed out, there are also CPAN modules to do this for you.  I've shortened the length of your range for brevity of output in this case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Net::Works::Address;

my $lower = Net::Works::Address->new_from_string( string => '10.0.0.145' );
my $upper = Net::Works::Address->new_from_string( string => '10.0.0.150' );

foreach my $i ( 0 .. 255 ) {
    my $ip   = '10.0.0.' . $i;
    my $auth = check_ip( $ip );
    say "$ip is OK" if $auth;
}

sub check_ip {
    my $ip = shift;
    my $address = Net::Works::Address->new_from_string( string => $ip );
    return ( $address <= $upper && $address >= $lower );
}
```

Output is:

```
10.0.0.145 is ok
10.0.0.146 is ok
10.0.0.147 is ok
10.0.0.148 is ok
10.0.0.149 is ok
10.0.0.150 is ok
```