# Passing @ARGS as shorthand to foreach(@ARGS) in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to pass values to foreach function in Perl from shell (while calling script).

```
user@system:$ perl perl_script @ARGS
```

Motivation: I've a list of 50 switches. 
*192.168.10.10 to 192.168.10.60* and 've to perform some action on all. so trying to pass it as a shorthand.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $t_args = $#ARGV+1;
print "Total args: $t_args\n";
print "[$_]\n" foreach @ARGV;
```

Output 1:

```
user@system:~/projects/learnperl$ perl counter.pl 12 13 14 15 16
Total args: 5
[12]
[13]
[14]
[15]
[16]
```

Output 2: ERROR

```
user@system:~/projects/learnperl$ perl counter.pl 12..16
Total args: 1
[12..16]
```

There are other ways to get through it, but i want to know if what i'm trying to achieve is possible.

Example usage:

```
user@system:$ perl getlogs.pl 10..60
my $network="192.168.0"
foreach my $node (@ARGS){
    my $ip="$network.$node";
    get_files_from ($ip);
}
```

This should get data from all my devices. 
It is understandable to do `foreach my $node (10..60)`. But i want to use `foreach my $node (@ARGS)`.

Comment: So you're asking how to generate the IP addresses from 192.168.10.10 to 192.168.10.60 in your shell? If so, we have to know which shell you're using. Of course, [you can do that with Perl too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279756/how-can-i-generate-a-range-of-ip-addresses-in-perl).

Comment: No .. i'm not asking that. I want to know how can i pass `12..16` as separate @ARGS using shell (bash) and Perl should expand it to `12 13 14 15 16` and not interpret it as 1 argument i.e `12..16`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** since you mentioned using the bash shell, it is possible to do
the range expansion at shell level. You don't have to change anything in
your initial code, just use:

```
$ perl getlogs.pl {10..60}
```

And it will send 51 separated arguments to the script.

---

You can use a module to process the range, like `Number::Range` or do it
with `eval` if you are sure about the security and validation of it. For
example:

```
my @numbers;

foreach (@ARGV) {
    if (/^\d+\.\.\d+$/) {
        # value is a range, eval it
        my @a = eval "($_)";
        push @numbers, @a;
    } else {
        # value assumed to be numeric, test if you want
        push @numbers, $_;
    }
}

print "Total args: ", scalar @numbers, "\n";
print "[$_]\n" foreach @numbers;
```

The module approach:

```
use Number::Range;

# if range detected ...
@a = Number::Range->new( $_ )->range;
```

Little test:

```
$ perl test.pl 10 11..14 15 16
Total args: 7
[10]
[11]
[12]
[13]
[14]
[15]
[16]
```

Comment: Ahh! Nice.
- Thanks for `eval` expression. Solves the problem.
- `$ script {10..20}`. **Amazing**.
- Will look into `Number::Range` at a later time.

Thanks :)