# Perl: Can a string be converted to vector flag

Tags: perl

I've been looking for a way to iterate through Ip range and I come across this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279756/how-can-i-generate-a-range-of-ip-addresses-in-perl)

```
sub inc_ip { $_[0] = pack "N", 1 + unpack "N", $_[0] }
my $start = 1.1.1.1;
my $end = 1.10.20.30;
for ( $ip = $start; $ip le $end; inc_ip($ip) ) {
    printf "%vd\n", $ip;
}
```

What I want to knew is if there is a way to convert string like `my $start = "192.168.1.1";` to vector flag. What I get when I pass a string is some random numbers

Comment: I don't understand what  this *"vector flag"* where you get some *"random numbers"* is you are talking about. And I cannot see anything in your code which matches this description. It is not clear from your question what you expect to happen and what you get instead.

Comment: If `my $start = 1.1.1.1;` ain't a vector flag? then what type of data it is?

Comment: This is an IP address. And a perl string.

Comment: Yeah it is, but I want to format a string to be a vector flag

Comment: I have no idea what this "vector flag" thing is you want. Please show what you expect the program to produce.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html, it is a format

Comment: There is no "convert to vector flag". This "vector flag" is a modifier ("flag") for `printf` to print the given value in a specific way. I still don't have any idea what you want your program to produce.

Comment: I want to enter an IP address as a string and pass it to `inc_ip()` and do the same work of the code

Comment: `Socket::inet_aton("1.2.3.4")` gives you the binary representation - which is what you likely want (don't forget `use Socket;`).

Comment: Your code is a bit tricky because your `$start` and `$end` variables are Version strings which carry some magic in perl...

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, Yeah that solve's it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pack 'C*', split /\./, $s
```

Or for IPv4 specifically,

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton );

inet_aton($s)
```

---

For example, you could use

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton );

my $start = unpack('N', inet_aton('1.1.1.1'));
my $end   = unpack('N', inet_aton('1.10.20.30'));

for my $ip ($start..$end) {
   printf("%vd\n", pack('N', $ip));
}
```

Comment: Added to my answer.